# TLS 1.0 not supported in Cloudflare

Tags: ssl, cloudflare

I set the minimum TLS supported to 1.0 however when I check the site using SSLLabs I see that only TLS1.2 and TLS1.3 are only supported. This is a newly created account. We have also another account which is created a year before and it supports TLS 1.0.

What should I do to support TLS 1.0 on our new CF account?

Comment: I would answer: Create a ticket for Support on Cloudflare

Comment: Update your application to support newer TLS versions. There is a reason TLS 1.0 is phased out.

Comment: I tried creating support ticket on Cloudflare or asking the community but it does not allow me. Maybe it's because I'm just using a free account not sure why. So I posted the question here instead

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not an option for us since the application was created by third-party developers so we can't update it.

Comment: @djdomi I created a support ticket here: https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/requests/2419212

Comment: shall we also ask now for your login credentials that we can access a ticket that only can be seen by you? ;) the only option i see is to put a reverse proxy in front of the application